# Multithreading issue with data parsing

Tags: ios, multithreading

I started a project to practice on where I parse JSON from Flickr and present the photos in my app. Everything works perfectly except when I try to practice multithreading the downloading portion of my app. I get the error message:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 4294967295 beyond bounds for empty array'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1c94012 0x10d1e7e 0x1c360b4 0x397f 0xf9103 0xf94df 0xfac4c 0xf97ef 0x2c2c0 0x2c245 0x2c095 0x1c5cafe 0x1c5ca3d 0x1c3a7c2 0x1c39f44 0x1c39e1b 0x1bee7e3 0x1bee668 0x15ffc 0x257d 0x24a5)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

This is the code that I attempt to thread:

```
-(void)loadFlickrPhotos {
    self.photoURLS = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    self.photoTitles = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    //Creating second thread here
    dispatch_queue_t downloadQ = dispatch_queue_create("Picture Download", NULL);
    dispatch_async(downloadQ, ^{

    NSString* urlstring = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?format=json&sort=random&method=flickr.photos.search&tags=rocket&tag_mode=all&api_key=0e2b6aaf8a6901c264acb91f151a3350&nojsoncallback=1"];
    NSURL* url = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:urlstring];

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSData* data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSDictionary *parsedObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];

    NSArray* photos = [[parsedObject valueForKey:@"photos"]objectForKey:@"photo"];

       for(NSDictionary* photo in photos) {

         NSString* photoURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://farm%@.static.flickr.com/%@/%@_%@_m.jpg", [photo objectForKey:@"farm"],[photo objectForKey:@"server"],[photo objectForKey:@"id"],[photo objectForKey:@"secret"]];

         NSString* photoTitleString = [photo objectForKey:@"title"];

         [self.photoURLS addObject:[NSURL URLWithString:photoURLString]];
         [self.photoTitles addObject:photoTitleString];
      }
         NSLog(@"Photo #: %i", self.photoURLS.count);
    }); //End of Second Thread
}
```

Comment: It would help if you pointed out the exact line causing the exception. It doesn't appear to be any of the code you posted.

Answer (score 0):

self.photoURLS & self.photoTitles are probably not thread safe properties...

do this 2 lines in the main thread

```
[self.photoURLS addObject:[NSURL URLWithString:photoURLString]];
[self.photoTitles addObject:photoTitleString];
```

Comment: I added  dispatch_queue_t mainQ right in the middle of my code with [self.photoURLS addObj etc... ] inside it. Is that what you had in mind?

Comment: dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
   [self.photoURLS addObject:[NSURL URLWithString:photoURLString]];
[self.photoTitles addObject:photoTitleString];                 
        });

Comment: yeah i tried that but still same thing. What im doing now is trying to separate the portion of code where It is looping from the rest of the method. Will see if that helps.

Comment: if your properties are define as nonatomic and you try to access it from a thread <> main thread you are no guaranty of the result. why specifically "<> main thread", because they have been create and access in the main thread.

Comment: no im using CS193p as some guidance but kind of working on it on my own. Just trying to get some practice with multithreading and parsing.  So what your saying is I should try and change my photourl and title arrays to not be nonatomic?